# Why is recursion causing the count to return 2 instead of 4?

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying to do the Balanced Tree question on Leetcode where you **return true only if height of left subtree - height of right subtree <= 1**.
Why is the depth of the left subtree returning a 2 when it should return 4? Is there something I am interpreting wrongly? I attached a picture of the tree at the bottom.

Input: [1,2,2,3,3,null,null,4,4,null,null,5,5]

Output: True (because left subtree is returning 2 instead of 4)

Expected Output: False

Print Statements:

left subtree: 2

right subtree: 1

result: 1 (left subtree - right subtree)

```
    /**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * public class TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode left;
 *     TreeNode right;
 *     TreeNode() {}
 *     TreeNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     TreeNode(int val, TreeNode left, TreeNode right) {
 *         this.val = val;
 *         this.left = left;
 *         this.right = right;
 *     }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    // 1 2 2 3 3 4 4
    // 
      
    if (root == null) return true;
    System.out.println("left subtree: " + findDepth(root.left,1));   
    System.out.println("right subtree: " + findDepth(root.right,1));   
    System.out.println("result: " + Math.abs(findDepth(root.left,1) - findDepth(root.right, 1)));
    if ( Math.abs(findDepth(root.left,1) - findDepth(root.right, 1)) <= 1) return true;
    return false;
    }
  
  public static int findDepth(TreeNode root, int count) {
    if (root == null) return count;
    if (root.left != null) {
       count++;
       findDepth(root.left, count);
    }
     if(root.left == null && root.right == null) return count;

    return count;
  }
    
}
```

[Image of Binary Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7IUO.png)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876255/how-to-calculate-the-depth-of-a-binary-search-tree) answer your question?

Comment: @Sweeper based on the debugger, the count reaches 4 then starts decreasing to 2. I am not sure why it would decrease when there is no count-- anywhere in the code. I'd like to understand why the recursion is decreasing the counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you get 2 is because when you recurse, the recursive call is not incrementing the `count` variable that you pass in. Instead, it increments its own *copy* of it. [Java is pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value).

```
if (root.left != null) {
   count++;
   // the call below will not change "count" at all
   findDepth(root.left, count);
   // it will only change its own copy
}
```

Therefore, the recursive call practically does *nothing*. You are not even using its return value. Its return value is actually the modified copy of `count` that you want `count` to be set to, so to fix this, set `count` to the return value of `findDepth`:

```
value = findDepth(root.left, count);
```

This will give you the expected 4, but your `findDepth` should also check the right subtree, and can be improved in other ways. For example, you don't actually need a `count` argument.

```
public static int findDepth(TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) return 0;
   
    return 1 + Math.max(findDepth(root.left), findDepth(root.right));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are only counting the depth of the left side of the tree in `findDepth` methof by applying condition

```
if (root.left != null) {
   count++;
   findDepth(root.left, count);
}
```

You can modify your method like this

```
  public static int findDepth(TreeNode root, int count) {
    if (root == null) return count;
   
    return Math.max(findDepth(root.left, count+1),findDepth(root.right, count+1));
  }
```

Comment: if (root.left != null || root.right != null) {
       count++;
       findDepth(root.left, count);
       findDepth(root.right, count);
    }  why does this not do anything? and thanks I'd like to upvote your comment but do not have enough reputation points!

Comment: Thanks... it will work if you read the return value from the `findDepth` method because when you pass the value to the function and then whatever happens inside the `method` with that value won't be reflected back as it is `pass by value` not `pass by reference`